# How to select pipe dependencies in Snowflake DB?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Snowflake DB contains [OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/object_dependencies) view. But the view doesn't contain pipe dependencies.

How can I get a list of objects that the pipe depends on?

Comment: Hi - what do you mean by "dependencies" in the context of a pipe? Do you mean the stage it is copying the data from, the table it is copying data to - or something else?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I mean table, stage and file format.

Comment: No - this information is not held as a "dependency list" anywhere. However, it would be reasonably straightforward to find this information by querying the relevant object definitions

Comment: Thanks, @NickW! I will look for workarounds. I have to get a list of dependencies automatically. A parsing of object definitions seems unsuitable to me.